# Why would iOS try to call rangeOfCharacterFromSet: on an NSIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation, unrecognized-selector

I'm getting the following error, which causes a `SIGABRT`:

```
2015-09-10 17:54:23.859 MyApp[1310:2027719] ERROR CRASH #(null) -[NSIndexPath rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000000016
2015-09-10 17:54:23.879 MyApp[1310:2027719] ERROR Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183840248 <redacted> + 160
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001952640e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838472f4 <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001838440a8 <redacted> + 928
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018374696c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000188632a44 <redacted> + 104
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001887a0ff0 <redacted> + 76
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001887a10b0 <redacted> + 56
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001887a1194 <redacted> + 36
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000187bf0820 <redacted> + 320
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187bf06c4 <redacted> + 32
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187befe58 <redacted> + 276
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187befbd8 <redacted> + 528
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187be9300 <redacted> + 80
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001837f7ff0 <redacted> + 32
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001837f4f7c <redacted> + 360
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001837f535c <redacted> + 836
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183720f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018d0436fc GSEventRunModal + 168
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000188322d94 UIApplicationMain + 1488
    20  MyApp                               0x00000001000437b0 main + 68
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000019590ea08 <redacted> + 4
```

which looks like iOS is trying to send a message to an `NSString` selector, but the message was sent to an `NSIndexPath`. Weird!

I've since found the problem; I'd set the value of the text in a `UILabel` to be a pointer to an object in a CoreData object's `NSNumber` column (`0xc000000000000016`) instead of an `NSString`. My fix was added `.intValue` to the `NSNumber` before passing it to my `enumToString:` method.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum)
{
    MyEnum1 = 1,
    MyEnum2,
    MyEnum3
};

- (NSString*)enumToString:(MyEnum)enumValue
{
    switch (enumValue) {
        case MyEnum1:
            return @"One";

        case MyEnum2:
            return @"Two";

        case MyEnum3:
            return @"Three";
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    // cdObject is a managed object in CoreData. Its enumValue column is an NSNumber.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self enumToString:cdObject.enumValue];
    return cell;
}
```

This just leaves the question: **Why would this cause iOS to try to send a message to the non-existant selector `-[NSIndexPath rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]`?**

The crash occurred just after completing a `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`

Comment: you should post the relevant code as it appears that error might as well be on your side as you could be passing incorrect object type to cocoa in the first place , which is often the case with these 'why would system do crazy thing' kind of errors, type checking is quite loose in objc  just in runtime so compiler might not save you from it entirely, that's why swift is so much more strict on types to prevent these kind of situations

Comment: @PetrV I've added example code.

Comment: The real thing that happens is that someone sends a message to a pointer to an object. However, that pointer no longer is a pointer to your NSString, but has been re-used and now points to an NSIndexPath. This can be the consequence of some unexpected deallocation (turn on zombies to find this out), or you are handling objects across threads and somewhere there is a part that is not safe. If this is the case, then you will get this problem not every time, but only once every n times you run.

Comment: @Joride well, I did get it every time. Strange that every time it pointed to an `NSIndexSet` and not the CoreData `NSNumber`.

Comment: @Joride sounds like an answer to me ;)

Comment: I see you've added code to your answer, but I don't see where that code uses `intValue`. What did the code look like before you made changes, when it produced the error? The simplest explanation is simply that you (somehow) set `cell.textLabel.text` to `indexPath`.

Comment: @robmayoff if you read my question more carefully, you'll realize that using `.intValue` is what solved my problem. This is what my code looked like when I could reproduce the error 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the cause is most likely not some threading gone wrong. Core Data turns the NSManagedObjects into faults at some point. This might be related. Also, NSNumbers are kind of special objects: the pointer is a tagged pointer, and this tagged pointer might contain the actual numeric value. This might also be related. In any case, a message was sent to a pointer, and that pointer no longer points to an object that recognizes that message. Read here about tagged pointers: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html